# Access Data on a Harvested GPT Protected SSD

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, ssd, gpt

I have an SSD drive that was in a Windows PC, the drive was GPT protected, 
I connected the drive via a dongle to an USB port.
My Linux machine is seeing the drive , but it appears empty with no partitions:

[image: Drive as be seen under Linux]

Is there any way I can get the data on that drive? 
I am willing to take it to a professional recovery service if there is a way, no matter how complicated. I am worried that they would simply format it and restore the data (partially probably).

Results of commands

```
 ls -laF /dev/sdb*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 dec 20 19:36 /dev/sdb


 sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
GPT PMBR size mismatch (1953525167 != 244190645) will be corrected by write.
Disk /dev/sdb: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 244190646 sectors
Disk model: 014-1EJ164      
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x39aa9229

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           1 244190645 244190645 931,5G ee GPT


    sudo blkid
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="73D8-D59A" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="adb40a15-a3c2-42bf-b8de-5d2f7630d9da"
/dev/sda2: UUID="c1c5db76-4aaf-4f62-8729-5737b3a6b19d" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="420ad540-f3b1-43d5-8306-7486d4c243fa"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop18: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop19: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop20: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop21: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop22: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop23: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop24: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop25: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop26: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop27: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sdb: PTTYPE="PMBR"




 dpkg -l | grep -i ntfs
ii  libntfs-3g883                              1:2017.3.23AR.3-2ubuntu1                 amd64        read/write NTFS driver for FUSE (runtime library)
ii  ntfs-3g                                    1:2017.3.23AR.3-2ubuntu1                 amd64        read/write NTFS driver for FUSE
ii  syslinux                                   3:6.04~git20171011.af7e95c3+dfsg1-6      amd64        collection of bootloaders (DOS FAT and NTFS bootloader)
```

Comment: There are too many possibilities for what you see. I doubt this can be properly answered. The drive can be physically defective or have any one of the several "not compatible with Linux" problems (dynamic disks, proprietary encryption, having been part of a software RAID, etc.). We simply don't know and shouldn't advise either way.

Comment: GPT is not a protection mechanism, but one scheme to store a partition table. Please append the output of the following command to your question (Do NOT add output as a comment): ```ls -laF /dev/sdb*```, ```sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb```, ```sudo blkid```, ```dpkg -l | grep -i ntfs```

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia The drive is not defetecd, I removed it from a laptop that had it's GPU burned, I am 100% the drive is okay

Comment: @user2976492 OK, not defective but I mentioned many other possibilities. Please post the information requested above. And if you can use some PC with Windows try it there to see if there's a difference.

Comment: @dirdi I have added the needed information

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I added the requested info

Comment: '(PMBR)' is the Protective master boot record, a boot sector on a hard disk with an MS-DOS-compatible format partition table embedded in it which also has a GUID partition table (GPT). It doesn't lock you out of making any changes.  Its purpose is to protect the disk contents from accidental damage by programs which properly interpret the MS-DOS-format partition table but do not interpret the GPT--for example, the fdisk program of both MS-DOS and Linux.

Comment: @K7AAY The drive appears  to be empty, On a windows machine I am unable to make any changes , it's basically locked , 
Note:  it was not encrypted

Comment: I'm sure others know more but I would have started with the `gdisk` tool to understand what's going on. If there is in fact a protective MBR partition covering the entire drive then the Disks app should at the very least not display it as "Free Space/Unallocated Space". Unless it's actually displaying the GPT partitions and there are no GPT partitions. Which would indicate that the Windows machine exclusively made use of the MBR partition table, given of course that it's true what you imlpy, that there were usable partitions on the drive when it switched machines.

Comment: Do you know if the Windows machine the SSD came from was a BIOS or a UEFI machine?

Comment: @Sirap  I am not sure about the BIOS / UEFI

Comment: Ok. I'm assuming here that Windows was installed on the SSD. If it were in fact a BIOS machine (older) then Windows would most probably have treated your SSD as only having a MBR partition table, even if it actually used the newer GPT partition table. Reason being that Windows refuses to boot from a GPT formatted disk if it's running on a BIOS system, which by process of elimination should mean that Windows treated it as an MBR disk.

Comment: fdisk's output shows that the GPT has a protective MBR but ls's output indicates that Ubuntu was unable to find partitions. Could be a damaged GPT, but should not be a big problem. Please run ```sudo fdisk /dev/sdb```, press: p, enter, M, enter, p, enter, q, enter and append the output.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1507843/554702

Comment: I'd carefully analyze what's being written in the PMBR as well as in the two(!) copies of the GPT.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving from HDD to SSD - facing some issues (GPT protective partition)](https://superuser.com/questions/1507146/moving-from-hdd-to-ssd-facing-some-issues-gpt-protective-partition)